# Panel not displaying when it should be

Tags: c#

So in my very small program I am generating a random percentage and based off that percentage it should display one of two panels. However, it is only ever displaying one.

Here is my code:

```
Random random = new Random();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool button1Clicked = true;
        if (button1Clicked == true) { ITIpanel.Visible = true; }
    }

    private void ITIpanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ITItimer.Enabled = true; 
    }

    private void ITItimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      double rand = random.NextDouble();
      if (rand <= .50) { bluestimPanel.Visible = true; }
      if (rand >= .50) {  redstimPanel.Visible = true; }

      ITItimer.Enabled = false; 
    }

    private void bluestimPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       Trialtimer.Enabled = true; 
    }

    private void redstimPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Trialtimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Trialtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bluestimPanel.Visible = false;
        redstimPanel.Visible = false;
        Trialtimer.Enabled = false;
        ITIpanel.Visible = true; 
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, what do you expect to happen if `rand` is .505 (ish)?

Comment: Adding to Jon, why would you use timers? And why would you define a boolean as true and then check if it's true?

Comment: For fun, add a text field that you set with the value of rand and see what you are getting.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point. I overlooked that. I guess I could set both to .5 such that anything below .5 triggers one event and anything above .5 triggers a second event.

Comment: @YoryeNathan The timers are just a quick and dirty mock up as the program this will eventually be ported into makes use of timers, which are necessary in certain circumstances.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat I did the F9 and F10 and the only thing that came up was in the Program.cs code which I can fix. It should not issues with the Main.cs code, which I've provided above.

Comment: @cwdaniels: A simple "else" would be my preference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that in the TrialTimer_Tick method setting ITIPanel.Visible to true is not causing ITIPanel to repaint and hence ITITimer never restarts.

You can put a breakpoint in the ITITimer_Click method and see if it is ever invoked again after the first invocation.